# Logging exceptions in fire&forget tasks

Tags: c#, exception, task

I try to start some action in background, I am not interested in its result, but in case of an error I'd like to log it, and - of course - prevent the application (here: a Windows service) from crashing.

```
    public static void CreateAndStartTaskWithErrorLogging(Action _action, string _componentName, string _originalStacktrace = null)
    {
        DateTime started = HighPrecisionClock.Now;
        Task task = new Task(_action);
        task.ContinueWith(_continuation => _continuation.LogExceptions(_componentName, started, _originalStacktrace));
        task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        task.Start();
    }
    internal static void LogExceptions(this Task _t, string _componentName, DateTime _started, string _originalStacktrace = null)
    {
        try
        {
            _t.Wait(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(_componentName, $"An exception occurred in a fire-and-forget task which was started at {_started}.\r\n" +
                                            $"The original stack trace is:\r\n{_originalStacktrace}");
            Logger.LogException(_componentName, ex);
        }
        try
        {
            _t.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception dex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(_componentName, dex);
        }
    }
```

Without `ConfigureAwait(false)` and without `_t.Dispose()`, the `catch` works and logs the exception. But the application crashes several seconds later (i.e. on the Finalizer thread?). The entry in the Microsoft Event Viewer shows that exception.

With `ConfigureAwait` and `_t.Dispose()`, I do not see the exception in the logs, the application just crashes.

What's wrong with the idea shown above?

Edit:

Meanwhile I tested without `ConfigureAwait` but with `_t.Dispose`. I could catch about 10 such exceptions, and none made the application crash. That seems to solve the issue, but I do not understand the reason for that, so the situation is still bad.

What does `ConfigureAwait(false)` do to Exceptions in the task (or in tasks started within that task, e.g. by a Parallel.ForEach further down)?

Why does the `Dispose` - which is called on the continuation, not the task proper according to a comment - prevent the crash (the Finalizer does not call Dispose, but Dispose may set some flags influencing its behavior)?

Edit 2:

Also that does not work all the time, only most of the time. Suggested solution 1 below also fails sometimes.

In the crashing context, the function is called with `Utilities.TaskExtensions.CreateAndStartTaskWithErrorLogging(() => DataStore.StoreSyncedData(data), Name);`, where `DataStore` is set to a composite which in turn calls `Parallel.ForEach(m_InnerDataStores, _store => { _store.StoreSyncedData(_syncedData); });` on its members. One of them writes a video with the Accord library, which sometimes causes an `AccessViolation` at `<Module>.avcodec_encode_video2(libffmpeg.AVCodecContext*, libffmpeg.AVPacket*, libffmpeg.AVFrame*, Int32*)`, i.e. the exception may come from non-managed code.

Of course, I could try to catch it somewhere down there - but that's not the objective of this method. I expect it to be able to safely run any code in the background without crashing the application.

Comment: Don't guess where the error is, post the full stack trace.

Comment: In your case `_t` is not `task` rather the task of the continuation itself, so that task disposes itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion for logging errors:

```
public static void OnExceptionLogError(this Task task, string message)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // Log t.Exception
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var task = Task.Run(action);
task.OnExceptionLogError("Oops!");
try
{
    await task;
}
catch
{
    // No need to log exception here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Of the last 6 errors, it could catch 5 of them. With one error, it did not even log the error, but the application crashed.